# Zooming to a specific Point on SurfaceView

Tags: android, graphics, android-layout

I've got the following problem:
I display a point on a SurfaceView (e.g. one specific pixel like (x=100,y=100)
on the screen.

Now I want to zoom to this specific point with different zoomlevels.
The zoomlevels are calculated by different scaleFactors. But I don't know
how I can display and scale the specific part of the screen?

Perhaps it would be also possible to move to the known displayed parts by "Scrolling about the screen" (using an OnTouchListener).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to `Canvas.scale()` to the specific point in the drawing loop of the `SurfaceView`?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#scale%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29